# Appending data to jQuery data-tables via AJAX is not using data-tables pagination and functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

http://www.datatables.net/

jQuery datatables is a plugin to add filters, pagination, and a search input.  I've been using them alongside my Laravel application to put the data into and it's been working fine.

I have now added a dropdown filter separate from the datatables and I have added some jQuery code that looks like this:

```
$('.dropdownselect').change(function() {
    $('.table').find('tr').remove();

    $.post('/schedules', { value: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(k, v) {
            $('.table-body').append('<tr><td>' + v.name + '</td></tr>');
        });
    });
});
```

It simply removes the values on change and appends the new values returned by the `schedules` route into the table.  In reality there are 4 more `<td>` in there but for simplification purposes I've only included one.

When using the code above it does not maintain the functionality of the datatables plugin.

Why is this?  Is there a way around it?  Or a better way to do this?

Comment: [http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding new rows to your DOM through your AJAX request won't notify the DataTables object container of these changes. You need to use `Datatable.row.add()` to insert the rows, and then redraw the table to visually update the tables display to account for this new data.

Try the following.

```
$('.dropdownselect').change(function() {
    $('.table').find('tr').remove();
    var t = $('.table').DataTable();

    $.post('/schedules', { value: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(k, v) {
            t.row.add( [v.name, v.otherParam, v.anotherParam] );
        });
        t.draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: For some reason this is appending duplicates of every record.  Also when I change the dropdown filter again, it doesn't get rid of the old rows.

Comment: I've fixed the second problem.  Read the API docs.  First problem still persists, however, I think it may be an issue that's unrelated.  Thanks for the help.